# CANopen emergency message implementation

Tags: canopen

I need to use emergency messages to send out error messages to the master. The reason I want to use emergency over [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Process_Data_Object_(PDO)_protocol) messages is that I want it to be quick.

I read a book called "Embedded Networking with CAN and CANopen", and it gave me almost a good understanding of CANopen. I am able to do send [emergency messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen#Emergency_Object_(EMCY)_protocol) with the help of CO_error() and CO_EM_process(), but I feel like I am missing something and I couldn't find any implementation examples to get a clear idea about the implementation workflow.

I am new to CANopen and the documentation about the libraries are confusing. What can I do? Or is there some source code that I can use as an example?

Comment: Are you implementing a CANopen stack from the ground-up or adapting an existing one? Also note that EMCY messages puts the network in pre-operational mode and as per the CANopen spec, nodes aren't allowed to transit to operational mode while there are errors pending. Meaning you won't be able to send PDOs until the error is cleared.

Comment: Re *"CO_error() and CO_EM_process()"*: What library and/or system?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*. Perhaps somebody else can chime in?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the authors of the book you mention, thanks for reading!
EMCY objects/messages are meant to signal error conditions on the bus and by default cause a switch from operational (PDO communication) to pre-operational (no PDO communication) mode. The overriding error behavior is configurable in object 1029h "Error behavior object" if it exists.

It is entirely feasible that you transmit EMCY messages for errors but whether the stack you use implements error handling including object 1029h correctly I can't say. If not then yes, when you send an error this way you have to switch yourself to pre-operational if you're currently operational, or you implement 1029h, too, and do whatever this object is configured to.

You can request a copy of the CiA 301 standard where all of this is specified [here](https://www.can-cia.org/groups/specifications/).
For a general overview of all important communication objects in CANopen including EMCY, as well as some other core concepts, see [this poster in PDF format here](https://www.can-cia.org/fileadmin/resources/documents/brochures/co_poster.pdf).